# Prediction model with constraint / penalty

Tags: regression, machine-learning, econometrics, regularization

I am attempting to predict rental price (Sq/ft) for a Retail space. I have a vector of demand / economic variables and other control variables such location and time fixed effects. I'd like to add a constraint to the model for balancing loss due to vacancy.

The data is at monthly level.

Model specification:

```
Pt = b0 + b1*Dt + b2*Lt + b3*Vt + b4*St + b5*Sup + e 

where, 

Pt = Rental Price
St = Type of the space - categorical variable 
Dt = Demand variables
Lt = Location variables
Sup = Available comparable supply / Vacancy
Vt = Loss due to vacant days ($) 

Vt is the constrain in the model.
```

I am looking for advise on:

1. Appropriate model to use (Linear or Non-Linear) and metrics to use for evaluation.
2. How to treat constraint variable? Regularization or other approaches?
3. Fit a model separately for space type or if included as a variable, how do I estimate the effect of each space type (categorical variable) separately?

Comment: Just adjust for the vacancy in the model as usual.  Your functional form specifies it as a linear effect, so no reason you can't just treat it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I could be misunderstanding the question but I think it's worth distinguishing between whether we are regressing or optimizing. From your equation is looks like $V_t$ is an input variable which you are using to make predictions.

However from your phrasing of the question it sounds more like $V_t$ is itself an function of price and you are looking to maximise price while also trying to minimise the vacant days. This is a bit of a different problem.

If you're trying to predict what the rental price of a space will be given some data then you can postulate the linear relation you defined above and do simple linear regression to estimate the best coefficients.

On the other hand for the second case, you might want to do an optimization to find what price you should set for a particular retail space. This would involve looking for the price which will maximise your profit. Where profit will have some relation like:

\begin{equation}
\textit{Profit}_t=N_{occ}P_t-N_{unocc}C_t
\end{equation}

Where $N_{occ}$ is the number of occupied days, $N_{unocc}$ is the number of unoccupied and $C_t$ is the cost of an unoccupied day. Here we would expect that there on constraints that the total number of days ($N_{occ}$+$N_{unocc}$) is fixed and that their split is in turn affected by the price $P_t$ (more expensive space will have fewer occupied days). We would probably also expect that the number of vacant days for a given price will depend on your other variables (quality of location etc.).

Happy to discuss more in comments if I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: good point, the question is a Optimization problem. I was trying to add vacancy as a penalty term in linear model. Basically, maximizing the profit with the constraint of minimizing loss due to unoccupancy. How would we include the constraint in the prediction model / specify this as optimization problem?

Comment: Does the dataset you are working with have data for Vacancy so that we can build a model for how vacancy depends on the other variables? I think what we want here is not a model for the price but rather a model for how vacancy depends on price (given all of the other factors). Once we have that model we just need to search for the price that maximises $(1-v_t(p_t))p_t$.

Comment: we have vacancy rate. So, we want to fit a mode with vacancy as dependent variable? `Vt ~ Pt + Dt + Lt` where, `Vt` = Vacancy rate, `Pt` = Rental Price and `Dt` and `Lt` as demand / location variables? Once we fit the model how do we search of price that maximizes (1−()) ?

Comment: I think it should be as straightforward as running a for loop over values of price and calculating predicted vacancy/profit and just looking for the value of price which maximises profit.

Comment: I see, so once we have the predicted vacancy rate, we calculate profits and find Rent where profits are maximum?

Comment: I think so. You can train a model which will relate Vt to Pt, Dt and Lt. Then for a particular property where you know the values for Dt and Lt, you can just pass in values of Pt, generate values for Vt using your model and then compute what those values of Pt and Vt translate to in terms of profit. I'm sure there's more complicated ways but that should be the easiest way.

Comment: You also probably want to constrain your model to search around reasonable values for Pt. And caveat to all this: this is a very simple model for the price vs vacancy trade off. You may need to make this equation more complicated to avoid an edge case where your model tells you the optimal situation is to have the property occupied for 1 very expensive day.